# Stripe API - How to start a trial period after a month then unsubscribe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

So I was wondering if this is possible on stripe starting a trial period for two months after a paid month for $xx and when the trial ends It will unsubscribe them automatically to the plan.

I don't know if this is the method I'm looking for, I'm open for suggestions like after the first invoice of the subscription I will add Discount Coupon for 100% for the next 2 month then unsubscribe right after the third invoice.created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be simpler to set the recurrence to 3 months. Then you could add a webhook subscriber to `invoice.created` events, which occur about an hour before payment is taken, and cancel the subscription when an event (with maybe some logic if this only applies to certain plans) is received. Your logic is significantly reduced in this way.

As you mentioned, you could apply a 100% discount, with a `repeating` duration with `max_redemptions` set to 2. I have a feeling that this will be more complex to manage - though possible.

I'm not sure about retrospectively adding trial to an existing subscription - I think it's only available on creation.

Comment: Yeah that would be much more simpler approach. Thank you.